# Issues getting multiple user details from a person or group column in a SharePoint list with Powershell Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: api, powershell, sharepoint

I have been using PowerShell to get some site and admin details out of a SharePoint list by using `Invoke-WebRequest`. In the list there are 3 person or group columns, two are for the primary and secondary admins where the last is for the sites admin group and lists its members.

The issue I'm encountering is while I can expand the primary and secondary admin fields to get there names/email addresses etc. If I use the exact same thing for the admin group it comes back with a 400 error.  I suspect this is due to the admin column having its allow multiple selection ticked and so I'm not expanding it correctly.

This is the Uri that works for the 2 admin columns:

> site url etc./_api/web/lists(guid''siteGUID'')/items?$select=*,Secondary_x0020_Contact/EMail,Secondary_x0020_Contact/FirstName,Secondary_x0020_Contact/LastName,Primary_x0020_Contact/EMail,Primary_x0020_Contact/FirstName,Primary_x0020_Contact/LastName&$expand=Primary_x0020_Contact,Secondary_x0020_Contact

This one returns the error when I add the 3rd person column to be expanded:

> site url etc./_api/web/lists(guid''siteGUID'')/items?$select=*,Secondary_x0020_Contact/EMail,Secondary_x0020_Contact/FirstName,Secondary_x0020_Contact/LastName,Primary_x0020_Contact/EMail,Primary_x0020_Contact/FirstName,Primary_x0020_Contact/LastName,Admin_x0020_Group/EMail,Admin_x0020_Group/FirstName,Admin_x0020_Group/LastName&$expand=Primary_x0020_Contact,Secondary_x0020_Contact,Admin_x0020_Group

I have also tried to just expand the admin group with out the others with this uri but it also gave the same error:

> site url etc./_api/web/lists(guid''siteGUID'')/items?$select=Admin_x0020_Group/EMail,Admin_x0020_Group/FirstName,Admin_x0020_Group/LastName&$expand=Admin_x0020_Group'

As for the header etc. I'm using the following:

```
$headers = @{accept = "application/json;odata=verbose"}
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers  -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Any advice on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using developter tools in the browser (F12), to see what the request url looks like when you expend it yourself?

Comment: No i haven't, i'm very new to API stuff and didn't realise you can do that.  Thanks for the tip - i'll give it a go =)

Comment: What you need to do is press F12 at the place you open the things manually you would like to see. If you check at the network tab, you will see loads of request but some of them are Get-requests. When you press them, you can see what call SharePoint Online has made to provide the information you requested. The request URL when you click the call will be the one you are looking for!

Comment: Just a quick example, if you are looking for the url to see permissions on a list item. Just press it and a call will appear in the network tab, starting with GetSharingPermissions?blablabla => Open that call and the request url is: 'https ://yoursite.sharepoint.com/general/SomeSubSite/_api/web/Lists(@a1)/GetItemById(@a2)/GetSharingInformation?@a1=%27%7BCA66CD00%2DFC98%2D4FBC%2D9A85%2D2E2B201609E6%7D%27&@a2=%271%27&$Expand=permissionsInformation,pickerSettings'

Comment: Thanks for you feedback Bernard , I've been looking over the network tab while on the target list but i haven't come across anything that looks like your example or related to the admin group. I should have said in my initial question this is for a SP2013 list. i unsure if that has any impact on this. I'll keep looking

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try also is the following. Since there are several ways of using SharePoint Online. One of my favorite ways is by installing the SharePoint Online SDK. This comes with dll files which you can then add to your script. See below example script which creates a query on a certain subsite and then loops through all the results and writing out the 'Employees'-tab.

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"

$UserName = "admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = "yourpassword"
$Url = "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/subSite"
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
$listTitle = "Title of the list containing the items you want to query"

$list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
$fields = $list.Fields
$qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery(10000,'ID','Created','Modified','Title','Employees')
$items = $list.GetItems($qry)
$Context.Load($fields)
$Context.Load($items)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($item in $items){
    $item.FieldValues['Employees']
}
```

What you see above is an example script which is able to query items from a list. In the foreach-loop I loop through all items found on the List and write out the employees tab. In my CreateAllItemsQuery I give the command to get the 'ID' the 'Title' etc. All of these values I can address after this.

Another way of querying your SharePoint Online environment is by using the webrequest:

Example to query permission information for a specific folder on a specific list which I generated by recreating this exact url when opening the folder sharing permissions:

```
$baseUri = "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com"
$clientId = 'YourClientId'
$clientSecret = 'YourclientSecret'
$resource = '00000002-0000-0fe2-ce00-000000000000/yoursite.sharepoint.com@7b60bad-9ab2-45d0-a2ac-c2c4ght4f7e'
$body = @{
    grant_type = 'client_credentials'
    client_id = $ClientId 
    client_secret = $ClientSecret
    resource = $Resource
}
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri 'https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/7b40dcad-9fe2-44d0-a0cc-c2d32f008f7e/tokens/OAuth/2' -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Body $body
$accessToken = ($result.content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token

$headers = @{
    accept = 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
}
$listId = "2BD249F3-1847-4972-835S-99266DC415"
$itemId = "2"

$uri = $baseUri + "/Lists(@a1)/GetItemById(@a2)/GetSharingInformation?@a1='{$listId}'" + "&@a2='$itemId'" + '&$Expand=permissionsInformation,pickerSettings'

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
($result.content | ConvertFrom-Json).d.permissionsInformation.links.results.linkDetails.Invitations.results
```

As you can see there are multiple ways to interact with SharePoint Online. And basically the last option is mainly looking into the requests in Developer Tools (F12) and find the exact query SharePoint does itself and replicate that URL. The first one is with the help of dll files which requires additional installation.

As you can see there are loads of options. If you aren't able to find the correct url to perform a webrequest, the first option might be interesting. It takes a lot of trial and error but I hope this helps you.

Comment: Again thank you Bernard for your feedback, I'll have a go at these when i'm back on shift and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply on this , while i haven't managed to fix the initial problem i have found a work around and thanks to your example i also found another issue with my string.  Thanks again for you help it is appreciated =)